# What is the format of the group member assignment in rust-rdkafka?

Tags: rust, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I'm using [rust-rdkafka](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka) to make myself a small client to manage kafka. I was trying to discover what topics a consumer group is connected to.

I tried getting the groups with this method `let groups = consumer.fetch_group_list(None, Duration::from_secs(5))` and then access to the connected topics with `groups.get(0).members().get(0).assignment()`. The problem is that the `assignment &[u8]` returned seems to have a wierd format. Something like `| 8 bytes of buffer | topic-name | 12 bytes of buffer | topic-name | ... | 14 bytes of buffer |`. Does anybody know if that's a kafka standard? Is there any documentation about this that I can check out? The crate uses librdkafka so I figured it could be something related directly to the C library.

If you know another way of getting the topics consumed by a group I would also appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of parsing the assignment. It is not supported officially but there's a PR about it in need for a test https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/pull/184

Comment: Can you show the code you were able to parse it with?